# How to make a Path spin in place?

Tags: wpf, animation, rotation

Microsoft gives a nice [example of a button spinning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-make-an-element-spin-in-place) in place when clicked. I want to achieve the **same effect with a path** but following the same approach does not have the same result.

For instance this path bellow,

```
<Path x:Name="path"
              Stretch="None"
              Stroke="Black"
              Fill="Blue"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
              Margin="100">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry Figures="M10,0 A10,10 0 0 1 7,7 L71,71 A100,100 0 0 0 100,0Z" />
            </Path.Data>
            <Path.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="MyPathTransform"
                                 Angle="0" />
            </Path.RenderTransform>
            <Path.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.MouseDown">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyPathTransform"
                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                             From="0.0"
                                             To="360"
                                             Duration="0:0:1" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Path.Triggers>
        </Path>
```

Invoking a click to that path does not make the latter spin in place, like the button does. Why does this happen and how may I fix it?

Comment: I copied your code into a WPF project and it works for me if I click on the path. What do you mean by invoking a click? Are you not actually clicking on it?

Comment: I mean by clicking the path it does not spin in place, like the button does. @JasonTyler. To make it more clear, the path moves and rotates, the button just rotates around itself.

Answer (score 1):

From your follow up comment, I understand the issue is that it does animate, but it does not spin in place like the button did in the tutorial you followed.

The rotation is very dependent on whatever your `RenderTransformOrigin` is set to, and this value is a percentage of the animating control's width and height. In your case, your `Path`boundaries are actually somewhat large. The `Path` is filling the container except for the 100 `Marign`. Your animation origin is set to 0.5, 0.5 (the center).   So it's in effect rotating around the center on the window. You can play around with that origin until you get in the center of your geometry, but an easier way to get and what you want would be to put your path in a `Canvas`. That way the `Canvas` will take up all the space and your `Path` will only be as large as your geometry. Then using a 0.5, 0.5 origin will do what you want.

```
<Canvas Margin="100">
    <Path x:Name="path"
          Stretch="None"
          Stroke="Black"
          Fill="Blue"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry Figures="M10,0 A10,10 0 0 1 7,7 L71,71 A100,100 0 0 0 100,0Z" />
        </Path.Data>
        <Path.RenderTransform>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="MyPathTransform"
                             Angle="0" />
        </Path.RenderTransform>
        <Path.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Path.MouseDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyPathTransform"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)"
                                         From="0.0"
                                         To="360"
                                         Duration="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Path.Triggers>
    </Path>
</Canvas>
```

Comment: *your Pathboundaries are actually somewhat large*. You hit the bull's eye with that. I can't understand why the boundaries are so large comparing to the path.

Comment: It has to do with the layout rules, I believe. Assuming you have the same case I do, the `Path` is the `Window` child. Since the `Path` has no size, I think it's stretched to fill the space. You can see the same thing happen if you add a `Button` as the child. Another way to get what you want would be to set the `Width` and `Height` of your `Path` to match your geometry. If they are set, the layout engine will respect it. The `Stretch` property on `Path` has more to do with how the geometry is laid out within your `Path`.

Comment: I have to agree that this trick was the best I got so far, but unfortunately it does not work. It just produces a better result. For example if you swap the `Path`'s data to `<RectangleGeometry Rect="10 10 20 20" />` then you'll see it.

Comment: Again this is a case where you've drawn some geometry "off-center" within the `Path` boundaries, so you can't use the center of the `Path`as your origin because that's what it will rotate about. In this case, you added a rectangle that's in the bottom right corner of your `Path`. If you had a rectangle that started at 0,0, using the center origin would work fine. Since you're offset by 10 and sized at 20, you need to account for that. In this case some simple math says your origin should be 0.66, 0.66. That puts your origin right in the center on your rectangle geometry.

Answer (score 1):

Animate the Transform property of the Geometry. Thus you have more precise control over the pivot point of the rotation.

```
<Path x:Name="path" Stretch="None" Stroke="Black" Margin="100">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry Figures="M10,0 A10,10 0 0 1 7,7 L71,71 A100,100 0 0 0 100,0Z">
            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform"/>
            </PathGeometry.Transform>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseDown">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="rotateTransform"
                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle"
                                     To="360" FillBehavior="Stop" Duration="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Path.Triggers>
</Path>
```